# Devide Siteap into 2 columns

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

[widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHuvm.jpg)

I'd like to know if it is possible to devide the text of my custom wordpress menue widget into 2 columns.

Comment: Can you post the code of your widget?

Comment: media="all"
footer .inner .widget:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
media="all"
footer .inner .widget {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
media="all"
footer .inner .widget {
    line-height: 20px;
}
user agent stylesheetdiv {
    display: block;
}

Comment: Please edit your question otherwise the code is not readable. Provide the php code to create the widget, the part in your template where you display it and the styling in css.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do it would be to set menu width to X, and then set width of the menu items/links to 0,5X. That way they will automatically resize into two columns. 
*When choosing suitable width, take account various paddings you may have.